# Getting blank data in a SalesForce integration with PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, salesforce

I am trying integration with SalesForce using SOAP webservice.

I can build a connection with PHP and SOAP after that if I'm trying to call my method that is authenticate user, I am not getting any data, I'm getting blank.

Below is the code

```
define("USERNAME", "xxxxxxxxxxx");
define("PASSWORD", "xxxxxxxxxxx");
define("SECURITY_TOKEN", "xxxxxxxxxxx");

require_once ('soapclient/SforcePartnerClient.php');
require_once ('soapclient/SforceHeaderOptions.php');

// Login
$sfdc = new SforcePartnerClient();
$SoapClient = $sfdc->createConnection('soapclient/PartnerWSDL.xml');
$loginResult = false;
$loginResult = $sfdc->login('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD' . 'SECURITY_TOKEN');


// Define constants for the web service. We'll use these later
$parsedURL = parse_url($sfdc->getLocation());
define ("_SFDC_SERVER_", substr($parsedURL['host'],0,strpos($parsedURL['host'], '.')));
define ("_WS_NAME_", 'CustomerPortalServices');
define ("_WS_WSDL_", _WS_NAME_ . '.xml');

define ("_WS_ENDPOINT_", 'https://' . _SFDC_SERVER_ . '.salesforce.com/services/wsdl/class/' . _WS_NAME_);
//echo _WS_ENDPOINT_;
define ("_WS_NAMESPACE_", 'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/' . _WS_NAME_);

// SOAP Client for Web Service
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/SFDC/soapclient/CustomerPortalServices_WSDL.xml');

$sforce_header = new SoapHeader(_WS_NAMESPACE_, "SessionHeader", array("sessionId" => $sfdc->getSessionId()));
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($sforce_header));


// username and password sent from Form

echo $myusername=addslashes($_POST['login_username']);
echo $mypassword=addslashes($_POST['login_password']);
try {

    // call the web service via post
    $wsParams=array(
    'username'=>'abc@gmail.com',
    'password'=>'mypassword'
    );
    print_r($wsParams);
    $response = $client->authenticateUser($wsParams);
    // dump the response to the browser
    print_r($response);
//header("location: index.php");
// this is really bad.
} catch (Exception $e) {
    global $errors;
    $errors = $e->faultstring;
    echo "Ooop! Error: <b>" . $errors . "</b>";
    die;
}
```

This is the method i am calling

```
global class CustomerPortalServicesNew {
 webService static Summary authenticateUserNew(String uname,String passwd) {
    System.debug('@@'+'Entered in the authenticateUser'); 
    List<contact> checkConList = new List<Contact>([select id,Email, Password__c, AccountId from contact where Email =:uname]);
    System.debug('@@'+'contact '+checkConList);
    for(contact c:checkConList){
        system.debug('@@'+'Iterating in contactList'+checkConList);
        if(c.Password__c==passwd){
            system.debug('@@'+c.AccountId);
            return getAccountSummary(c.AccountId);
        }
        else{
            system.debug('@@'+'password has not matched');
            return null;
        }
    }
    system.debug('@@'+'class finished');
    return null;
}
```

I am getting response like this

```
object(stdClass)[8]
```

public 'result' => 
    object(stdClass)[9]

not getting data

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to print:

```
print_r($response->result);
```

If it's not working, try a `var_dump($response)`

Comment: object(stdClass)[8]
  public 'result' => 
    object(stdClass)[9]                                                                                                     i am getting response like this how to get data from thos

Comment: What's the type of the result you defined in your method authenticateUser? What do you return?

Comment: Summary object
or null if login fails